# Batch updates to SQL Table wont stop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a large table (18 million records) which I am updating using the following batch update snippet:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rows INT, @count INT, @message VARCHAR(100);

SET @rows = 1; 
SET @count = 0;

WHILE @rows > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

        UPDATE TOP 100000 tblName
        SET col_name = 'xxxxxx'

        SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT
        SET @COUNT = @count + @rows
        RAISERROR ('count %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT

    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Even though the code has the @count increment logic, it races past the 18 million records I am trying to update. What am I missing here and what should I add/remove to make the updates stop at the 18,206,650 records that I have in the table?

Thanks,
RV.

Comment: why would it stop?, the update has no `WHERE` condition, so if the table has any rows, `@@ROWCOUNT` will always be > 0

Comment: But the update is always going to be that 1 statement. Its a blanket statement to mask certain data and no matter what data is in there, it has to be updated to xxxxx

Comment: I know I can add a silly where column <> xxxxxx and that should do it.

Comment: sorry, not sure how could I tell you what condition to add, I don't know which rows you want to update?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I was missing where clause on the update statement. Sorry y'all.